# HBase region - region server programmatic assignment

Tags: java, hbase

Let's say I have 100 `HBase` nodes and several tables `A, B, C` that have keys pre-pended with *000:099* prefixes. Tables are created with splits based on prefix, so each table has 100 regions.

I'd like to assign all rows with prefix:

- `000` to `node-00`,
- `001` to `node-01`,
- and so on.

The idea is to hold data with same prefix on the same machine, because my typical scenario is to process *table A*, transform the data and put it to *table B*, then process *table B* several times doing some transformations and aggregations.

I don't see the instruction in [docs](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/regions.arch.html) and need some suggestions about how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new table with need number of regions. Then do a manual region balancing before populating the table using **move** command, putting regions to the required servers. See help for it

```
hbase(main):004:0> help move

Here is some help for this command:
Move a region.  Optionally specify target regionserver else we choose one
at random.  NOTE: You pass the encoded region name, not the region name so
this command is a little different to the others.  The encoded region name
is the hash suffix on region names: e.g. if the region name were
TestTable,0094429456,1289497600452.527db22f95c8a9e0116f0cc13c680396. then
the encoded region name portion is 527db22f95c8a9e0116f0cc13c680396
A server name is its host, port plus startcode. For example:
host187.example.com,60020,1289493121758
Examples:

  hbase> move 'ENCODED_REGIONNAME'
  hbase> move 'ENCODED_REGIONNAME', 'SERVER_NAME'
```

Or you can try to use HBaseAdmin to do this, see method [move](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#move-byte:A-byte:A-).